# boost::property_tree put usage C++

Tags: c++, boost, ros, boost-propertytree

I am doing a `ptree.put()` inside a class member function.

```
class Writer{
private:
    boost::property_tree::ptree ptree_;
public:
    Writer(){}
    void setData1(string path, string data){
        ptree_.put(path, data);
    }
    void setData2(string path, string data){
        ptree_.put(path, data);
    }
    void printPtree(){
        boost::property_tree::write_json(std::cout, ptree_);
    }
};
```

I am creating an instance of the class and `setData1()` is called by a callback function in the code (Multiple ROS subscriber callbacks).

When I call `setData2()` in the `main()` it works as expected. But when the similar `setData1()` is called by the callback, `ptree_` is empty at the end. When I do both, `ptree_` only has the data written by `setData2()`.

When I print the `ptree_` inside `setData1()` at each call, data of that call can be seen in the `ptree_` but not the data written in previous calls. No data written using `setData1()` is there when `printPtree()` is called. Only data written using `setData1()` remains intact.

I wrote two identical `setData` methods so that I could explain my problem clearly. What I am doing wrong here?

---

EDIT: Here's a minimal version of my code. This is a ROS node.

```
class Writer{
private:
    pt::ptree ptree_;

public:
    Writer(){}

    void setData(string branch, string data){
        ptree_.put(branch, data);
        // gets ptree content at each call
        // pt::write_json(std::cout, ptree_);
    }
    ~Writer(){
        pt::write_json(std::cout, ptree_);
    }
};

class SubscriberHandler{
private:
    ros::Subscriber sub_;
    Writer writer_;
public:
    SubscriberHandler(string topic_name_, Writer & writer) : writer_(writer){
        ros::NodeHandle n;
        sub_ = n.subscribe(topic_name_, 10, &SubscriberHandler::callback, this);
    }
    // this is the ROS callback function
    void callback(const topic_tools::ShapeShifter::ConstPtr& msg){
        --- CODE TO GET DATA FROM msg---
        writer_.setData(path, value);
    }
};

class SomeClass{
    Writer writer;
public:
    SomeClass(){
        writer.setData("Velocity.x", "50");
        writer.setData("Velocity.y", "10.5");
        // I have to create these objects inside a class
        SubscriberHandler sh("my_topic", writer);
    }
};

int main(){
    ros::init("node_name");

    SomeClass sc;

    ros::spin()
    return 0;
}
```

This is the `ptree_` I have at the end

```
{
    "Velocity": {
        "x": "50",
        "y": "10.5"
    }
}
```

but if I print the `ptree_` at each call, it has the data sent at that particular call + the above. Since it seems like a problem related to my C++ knowledge, I have posted the problem here instead of ROS answers.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You first describe how `setData1` and `setData2` are *similar* and apparently have different behavior, but then you show them to be *identical*. That does not make things clearer. Please follow @Someprogrammerdude's advice.

Comment: At a guess you are copying your `Writer` object somewhere and modifying the copy rather than the original. Need a [mcve] to be more helpful.

Comment: I've added a minimal version of the code.
@AlanBirtles Yes the behavior suggests something like that but I don't see a reason for that to happen in my code

Comment: be careful : `sh` goes out of scope immediately, so you can't guarantee that the callback will be called while the object still exists. It might already have been destroyed by that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `Writer` instances :

- the `writer` member of the `SomeClass` instance created in `main`. The property tree in it has `"Velocity.x"` and `"Velocity.y"` set.
- the `writer_` member of the `SubscriberHandler` instance created in the `SomeClass` constructor. This is a copy of the first `Writer` instance (because the `SubscriberHandler` constructor copied it). The property tree in it has `"Velocity.x"`, `"Velocity.y"` and `path` set.

Comment: I got it now. I've asked such a stupid question. Thanks @Sander

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ : the easiest solution would be to make `writer_` a reference. That means you have to worry about the object lifetime though, so something like a `std::shared_ptr` might work better.